# Plotting multiple price chart in python

Tags: python, database, forex

I studied in udacity (im newbie)and i stuck at this. I coppy code and run but there is no output

this is udacity link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmF6iEQzC2A

*My csv files are different from the video

[here is my csv link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9jxAnOt9WL2VXNqNGhMWjQ4SzA)

here is my code

```
    """Slice and plot"""

import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_selected(df, columns, start_index, end_index):
    plot_data(df.ix[start_index:end_index,columns],title="Selected Data")

def symbol_to_path(symbol, base_dir="data"):
    """Return CSV file path given ticker symbol."""
    return os.path.join(base_dir, "{}.csv".format(str(symbol)))


def get_data(symbols, dates):
    """Read stock data (adjusted close) for given symbols from CSV files."""
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
    if 'EURUSDCSV' not in symbols:  # add EUR for reference, if absent
        symbols.insert(0, 'EURUSDCSV')

    for symbol in symbols:
        df_temp = pd.read_csv(symbol_to_path(symbol), index_col='DateTime',
                              parse_dates=True, usecols=['DateTime', 'Close'], na_values=['nan'])
        df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns={'Close': symbol})
        df = df.join(df_temp)
        if symbol == 'EURUSDCSV':  # drop dates SPY did not trade
            df = df.dropna(subset=["EURUSDCSV"])

    return df


def plot_data(df, title="Stock prices"):
    """Plot stock prices with a custom title and meaningful axis labels."""
    ax = df.plot(title=title, fontsize=12)
    ax.set_xlabel("Date")
    ax.set_ylabel("Price")
    plt.show()


def test_run():
    # Define a date range
    dates = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31')

    # Choose stock symbols to read
    symbols = ['EURUSDCSV', 'USDJPYcsv']  # SPY will be added in get_data()

    # Get stock data
    df = get_data(symbols, dates)

    # Slice and plot
    plot_selected(df, ['EURUSDCSV', 'USDJPYcsv'], '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_run()
```

Comment: You have a typo in the line before the `def` statement: `plot_data(df.ix[start_index:end_index,columns],title="Selected Data)"` should be `plot_data(df.ix[start_index:end_index,columns],title="Selected Data")`.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. But it still doesn't work. There is no error and output. Graph Should be appeared.

Comment: There might be a range of reasons -- it's hard to say, as we don't have your input. If I was you, I would start by checking if the `df` in `plot_data` actually contains some data (try `print(df)` or `print(len(df))` ). If it is empty, start searching from there.

Comment: i type "print(df)" below "return df" at the same position. No output

Comment: type it before `return df` otherwise the `print` command will not be executed.

Comment: i type "print(df)" above "return df" at the same position. No output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at line 9, the line previous to the reported error:

```
plot_data(df.ix[start_index:end_index,columns],title="Selected Data)"
```

The closing quote is in the wrong position, it should be before the closing parenthesis, i.e.

```
plot_data(df.ix[start_index:end_index,columns],title="Selected Data")
```

Comment: Thank you so much mhawke but it still does not work. No error but no output.

Comment: Well this did answer the question that you asked :) Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Since im newbie im not sure whether i understand debuging correctly or not. I just run debug and no error then i run the code and it still be the same